# New at Pro Tools, what is the best denoiser plug-in for dialogue?

Tags: cleaning

PLEASE ANY SUGGESTION ABOUT A BUNDLE WITH PLUGINS PARTICULARLY DEDICATED AT CLEANING NOISY DIALOGUE  AND A GOOD COMPRESSOR ?

Comment: @alidav, please don't use ALL CAPS - it makes some people uneasy…thanks!

Comment: I feel like this question has about 10 variants when you search keywords in the SEARCH FUNCTION.

Answer (score 4):

FOR NOISE REDUCTION LOOK AT IZOTOPE RX 2 OR WAVEARTS MASTER RESTORATION.

PLENTY OF COMPRESSORS AVAILABLE, CAN'T REALLY NAME ONE "GOOD COMPRESSOR" (BUT http://varietyofsound.wordpress.com/ IS NICE, AND THEY'RE AVAILABLE FOR FREE / FOR DONATIONS).

Answer (score 3):

+1 for iZotope RX2. I have done a series of videos for them showing in real time how RX2 can fix problems http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/rx/protips.asp

Also go to Groove 3 and take a look at my RX2 tutorial series with over 3 hours of video tutorials on how to get the most out of RX2 http://www.groove3.com/str/rx2-explained.html

As to a compressor, the Avid Channel Strip is working OK and is free, if you want to spend a bit of money take a look at the new Pro Compressor from Avid.

Mike.

Answer (score 1):

Rx is great but the whole learn/remove paradigm can be time consuming, although gives best results. For quick and dirty stuff i love automating the waves w43. Its cheap and reliable and although only native on new systems I normally run it in my first slot anyway, so its not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Although I use Pro Tools for sequencing and EQ/Mix/Mastering, for dialog, I've actually found Audacity to be leaps and bounds faster and easier (or really for almost all single-file editing). From clicking on the icon, to full software load, it is about 2.5 seconds, and you can bind almost all the keys/functions you want, including many effects, and macros. Plus, you don't have to bounce, you can just export your audio into most formats.

The Noise Removal tool is superbly slick and pretty easy to use, so here's my workflow:

I record the dialog through Audacity, use the Noise Removal tool, edit, export the audio, then bring it in to Pro Tools if I need to do some compression/EQ. I am currently not a huge fan of Audacity's compression or EQ, which is why I use Pro Tools for that. Using 2 DAWs might sound inefficient, but even using two instead of 1, I think I am about 25% more efficient since Audacity is so much quicker for dialog editing.

Lastly, Audacity's pencil, brush, and repair tools for dialog are a huge time saver as well. Great for taking out mouth sounds, etc.

Did I mention Audacity is free? Audacity is free.

Answer (score 0):

Best one hands down is Cedar DNS one

Answer (score 0):

The track volume fader.